# Use unknown number of variables to place the returns of a method

Tags: python, oop, methods

I have a method `__some_method` which might return one parameter, or two, or any number. I want to call this method in another one and place the returns into variables, like so

```
var1, var2 ... varN = self.__some_method()
```

Is there any way that one can do this, in a very general setting, such that it works for any number of returned parameters?

Comment: Sounds like a great place to start learning about arrays: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/python/3942-arrays-in-python.html

Comment: Use a magical [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to solve this problem.

Comment: I thought about arrays, however I am not sure it's the best choice for my problem. I was wondering if anything else would work.

Comment: return a tuple. It will be unpacked into your variables. You would have to be careful though as if the number of arguments don't match the number of variables there will be an exception. Arrays have a very [specific](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) meaning in python, the general purpose data structure referred to above is a `list`.

Comment: If you have an unknown number of return values, why not use a tuple/list? `var = self.__some_method()` (note you almost certainly shouldn't be using two underscores, not sure where you got that idea). What makes you unsure that's the best choice? What do the return values represent? Why don't you know how many there'll be? Without context, *just use a list* and stop wasting time wondering.

Answer (score 0):

I still think a dictionary is the best way to solve what you are trying to do. However, this does not go without saying that you should probably revise why it is you have a function that could return an indeterminate amount of variables. That seems like a bad decision. At the very least that return should be collected inside a data structure, so you know that you will have a single return type where you can deal with the contents yourself.

With that being said. If you are looking for some kind of way where you can assign *names* to these individual variables that will come back, you can make use of a dictionary to control this. Here is an example:

```
def foo(*args):
    return args


result = foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
var_pack = {'var_{}'.format(idx): data for idx, data in enumerate(result, 1)}

print(var_pack)
# {'var_7': 7, 'var_4': 4, 'var_8': 8, 'var_2': 2, 'var_3': 3, 'var_6': 6, 'var_1': 1, 'var_5': 5}

print(var_pack['var_8'])
# 8
```